# Get length of char array with null elements in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

Currently I am making a project that uses `char` arrays that have null elements. I want to be able to get the length of the array, in the sense of the number of elements that aren't null. This seemed reasonably trivial and I made this function:

```
int getWordLen(char word[]) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
        if (word[i] != '\0') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d ", count);
    return count;
}
```

However, every char array returns a length of 188. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the function I was calling it from:

```
void redact(Words * redactWords, char fileName[]) {
    FILE * file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    FILE * outputFile = fopen("outputFile.txt", "w+");

    char word[512];
    int i = 0;
    char c;

    while (c != EOF) {
        c = getc(file);

        if ((c > 96) && (c < 123)) {
            word[i] = c;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        else if ((c > 64) && (c < 91)) {
            word[i] = c + 32;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        i = 0;

        if (isWordRedactWord(redactWords, word)) {
            //write stars to file
            char starStr[512];
            for (int i = 0; i < getWordLen(word); i++) {
                starStr[i] = '*';
            }
            fputs(starStr, outputFile);
        }
        else {
            //write word to file
            fputs(word, outputFile);
        }

        strcpy(word, emptyWord(word));
    }

    fclose(file);
    fclose(outputFile);
}
```

Comment: Can you add how you're calling this function?

Comment: Put that code in the question.

Comment: Just added to the question :)

Comment: There may be characters after the `\0`.

Comment: maybe zero initialize? `char word[512] = "";`

Comment: Do not use `char` to compare to `EOF`. **Must be `int`**.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if you moved `i = 0;` to the bottom (of the loop) wouldn't `i` have the value you seek? Also, your inner loop declares a second variable named `i` (I suggest `j` instead).

Comment: Zero initialising didn't work

Comment: `while (c != EOF) { c = getc(file); ...` -> `while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) { ...`

Comment: There are many errors in the `redact` function, but no indication that you'll ever send a string to `getWordLen` that contains NUL characters inside the string. Missing the NUL terminator at the end? Sure. But that's a different issue.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I just did your comment and now the first word gives the right length and then it alternates from giving lengths of 0 and 10, then 0 and 12, then 0 and 15

Comment: @user3386109 well i declare all the words a "char word[512]" so i figured all the other elements would be null?

Comment: Declaring an array as a local variable leaves the elements uninitialized, i.e. the elements can have any value. You can force them to zero with an initializer, like `char word[512] = {0};` or `char word[512] = "";` But that's a one-time deal. If you put "HELLO" into the array, and then put "BYE" into the array, the array contents will be "BYELO".

Comment: So after putting "BYE" into the array, you need to put a NUL terminator `'\0'` after the `E`. That allows you to find the end of the string. It also allows the string to work with the string functions, like `fputs` and `strcpy`.

Comment: @user3386109 ahhh okay thank you! will try that :)

Comment: With `int getWordLen(char word[])`, `word` is not an _array_, but a _pointer_.  The calling code did not pass into `getWord()` any length information.

Answer (score 0):

In the initial while, I would only use `while(!EOF)`. 
Also, I believe you are using a lot more resources than necessary with the implementation of that `for` inside the `while`:

`char starStr[512];
            for (int i = 0; i < getWordLen(word); i++) {
                starStr[i] = '*';`

I suggest you to put it outside the while loop and see what happens.

If it is always giving you 188 of lenght, it is counting something that's constant, and may be related to that outer loop.

Hope you can solve it!